# HK2 service reification failed Warning in logs for javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo with exception: Could not find a suitable constructor in UriInfo class

Tags: java, jersey, glassfish, hk2, supplier

While calling certain Rest services, I am getting HK2 reification failed error.
Recently I migrated my application to Open jdk 12 from JDK 8.

I replaced AbstractBinder package from org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder to org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.AbstractBinder. Also, the custom bind factory class I am using was earlier implementing org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory but now I modified it to implement java.util.function.Supplier. This is giving me the mentioned error.
Please have a look at the code:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped;

public class AppBinder extends AbstractBinder
{
@Override
protected void configure() {
    bindFactory(CustomFactory.class).to(Search.class).in(RequestScoped.class);

}
}


import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

public class CustomFactory implements Supplier<Search>
{

@Inject
private ServiceLocator serviceLocator;

public CustomFactory() {
}

@Override
public Search get() {
    return this.getSearch(serviceLocator.getAllServices(UriInfo.class).get(0).getQueryParameters());
}
}
```

The custom bind factory is used to some other actions like closing connections etc. 
Am I doing it the right way or should I use a different approach in defining my custom factory and using it in the AppBinder class.

Comment: Can we see the exception?  Also, I'm not sure supplier will work properly or not

Comment: @jwells131313 I was looking at the way UriInfo worked earlier. Earlier serviceLocator.getAllServices(UriInfo.class).get(0).getQueryParameters() returned two query parameters ("off"  and "max"). However, the method is not returning any query parameters. Exception is as follows :
19:50:56,055 W - The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for [javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo] with an exception:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo class.

Comment: Try to just inject it instead of getting through ServiceLocator

Comment: Thanks @PaulSamsotha, I will surely try this. I would like to know your thoughts behind your suggestion. 
Is there any issue with ServiceLocator ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion by Paul Samsotha in the comments,the issue got resolved.

I injected the UriInfo object using @Context annotation and thereafter I could get the desired behavior by calling uriInfo.getQueryParameters().

Below is the new code :

```
public class CustomFactory implements Supplier<Search>
{

@Context
 UriInfo uriInfo;


@Override
public Search get() {
   return this.getSearch(uriInfo.getQueryParameters());
}
}
```